# A sequent calculus proof

Tags: logic, proof-theory, modal-logic, sequent-calculus

Consider the sequent calculus (with multiplicative contexts) defined by the following rules (without contraction and weakening). The sequent calculus is taken from p.23 here: http://users.ox.ac.uk/~cpgl0036/pdf/asudeh-giorgolo-perspectives.pdf):

$$ \frac{\qquad }{A \vdash A} \,{Id} $$

$$ \frac{\Gamma\vdash B \qquad B, \Delta\vdash C}{\Gamma, \Delta \vdash C} \,{Cut} $$

$$ \frac{\Delta\vdash A \qquad \Gamma, B\vdash C}{\Gamma, \Delta,  A \rightarrow B \vdash C} \,{\rightarrow L} $$

$$ \frac{\Gamma, A \vdash B}{\Gamma \vdash A \rightarrow B} \,{\rightarrow R} $$

$$ \frac{\Gamma \vdash A}{\Gamma \vdash \bigcirc A} \,{\bigcirc R} $$

$$ \frac{\Gamma, A \vdash \bigcirc B \qquad }{\Gamma, \bigcirc A \vdash \bigcirc B} \,{\bigcirc L} $$

I can prove $\bigcirc (A \rightarrow B) \vdash \bigcirc A \rightarrow \bigcirc B$ in this calculus, but not the converse $\bigcirc A \rightarrow \bigcirc B \vdash \bigcirc (A \rightarrow B)$. Is the converse provable? I cannot find a proof of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general recipe for answering such questions is based on a [cut-elimination theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem). The authors state in footnote 28 that the $Cut$ rule is "admissible" for this calculus, which is another way to say that it can be eliminated.[*] To decide whether $\bigcirc A \to \bigcirc B \vdash \bigcirc (A \to B)$ is provable, it therefore suffices to ask, "Does it have a cut-free proof?"

Now, any cut-free proof of $\bigcirc A \to \bigcirc B \vdash \bigcirc (A \to B)$ must necessarily end in either ${\to}L$ or ${\bigcirc}R$, as in one of the following proof attempts:
$$
 \frac{\vdash \bigcirc A \qquad \bigcirc B \vdash \bigcirc (A \to B)}{\bigcirc A \to \bigcirc B \vdash \bigcirc (A \to B)} {\to}L
\qquad
 \frac{\bigcirc A \to \bigcirc B \vdash A \to B}{\bigcirc A \to \bigcirc B \vdash \bigcirc (A \to B)} {\bigcirc}R
$$
The first possibility can be immediately eliminated because it is not possible to prove $\vdash \bigcirc A$ for arbitrary $A$ (take $A$ to be any atomic formula). The second possibility can likewise be eliminated through a bit more case analysis of cut-free proofs: eventually we would be required to prove $\bigcirc B \vdash B$, but this is not possible for general $B$.

Therefore, $\bigcirc A \to \bigcirc B \vdash \bigcirc (A \to B)$ is not provable for general $A$ and $B$.

[*] technically, a rule is *admissible* for a sequent calculus if given derivations of the premises, we can construct a derivation of the conclusion without using the rule itself. In particular, the $Cut$ rule is admissible if given cut-free derivations of $\Gamma \vdash B$ and $B, \Delta \vdash C$, we can always construct a cut-free derivation of $\Gamma,\Delta \vdash C$.

---

**Edit**: Of course, the extra bit of reasoning which is missing from this argument is the proof of cut-elimination itself which the authors claim in the footnote. That is usually done on a case-by-case basis for a particular sequent calculus, and is a good exercise (you can find an example for another sequent calculus in these [lecture notes by Frank Pfenning](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15317-f09/lectures/10-cutelim.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks. You can actually prove $\bigcirc A$ for arbitrary A, given that the sequent is as the $\bigcirc R$ rule describes. That is, from $A \vdash A$, we can move to $A \vdash \bigcirc A$. However, that move wouldn't work for your first proof attempt, since the "A" would have to then be present in the lower sequent. In fact, though, I've found that, although we don't have $B \vdash B$ for all formulas, for some we do; in fact, we have $\bigcirc (A \rightarrow \bigcirc B)  \equiv A \rightarrow \bigcirc B).

Comment: What I was also trying to find out was whether we have $\bigcirc (M \land N) \vdash \bigcirc M \land \bigcirc N$, when we add a multiplicative conjunction to the language with the rules $$ \frac{\Gamma\vdash A \qquad \Delta\vdash B}{\Gamma, \Delta \vdash A \land B} \,{\land R} $$ and $$ \frac{\Gamma, A, B \vdash C \qquad}{\Gamma, A \land B \vdash C} \,{\land L} $$. We seem to have the converse.

Comment: Also, if we are working in intuitionistic logic with the modality $\bigcirc$ we seem to have $\bigcirc (A \rightarrow B) \equiv \bigcirc A \rightarrow \bigcirc B$, so adding contraction and weakening to the rules above must mean that at least one of your two proof attempts can be mended in an intuitionistic setting.

Comment: When I say that it is not possible to prove $\vdash \bigcirc A$ for arbitrary $A$, I mean with an empty left-hand side, as required to invoke the ${\to}L$ here. It is true that $\bigcirc B \vdash B$ (I think that's what you meant to write, rather than $B \vdash B$) holds for _some_ $B$, though, in particular for any $B$ of the form $B = \bigcirc C$.

Comment: Yes, that's right, I meant $\bigcirc B \vdash B$

Comment: I don't think that $\bigcirc(A \to B) \equiv \bigcirc A \to \bigcirc B$ holds intuitionistically. (In the intuitionistic case this is called "lax logic", see section 7 of https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/papers/mscs00.pdf.)

Comment: I believe that the argument I gave in the answer for why $\bigcirc A \to \bigcirc B \vdash \bigcirc (A \to B)$ is not provable for arbitrary $A$ and $B$ can be adapted without difficulty to the intuitionistic case.

Comment: By the way, if this answers your original question, please don't forget to accept the answer :-)

Comment: Perhaps you would also be able to help with a similar question I just asked on a tableau for intuitionistic S4 modal logic. :)